# C# RegistryKey.GetValue doesn't return blank lines

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

So I'm writing some code and using `RegistryKey.GetValue` and I can't seem to get it to return the proper string array.  I would use RegSaveKeyEx except I need to change the location of where the keys are being saved to in the reg file I'm creating.

The MultiString I'm querying has two lines in it, `:` and a blank line.  Regedit gives `hex(7):3a,00,00,00,00,00` for the reg file export of said value.  This is correct.  3a would be `:`, then a null, two nulls for the blank line and finally two more nulls to signify the end of the value.  My code is giving `hex(7):3a,00,00,00`, which would be a `:` and the double-null EOL characters on a MultiString.  When imported back into the registry `hex(7):3a,00,00,00` is only a `:`, the blank line is missing.

If I import `hex(7):3a,00,00,00,00,00` then view the value in regedit, I see `:` and a blank line. This is correct and this is what I want my code to do.

When I query this value with `RegistryKey.GetValue` in C# 4.0 I get the a `string[]` with just one element, the `:`.

For other MultiString values I get an array containing an element for every line, as I would expect.

`RegistryKey.GetValue` doesn't return anything for the blank line.  It doesn't return a null, a blank string in the array, nothing.

On everything except blank lines it returns exactly the same result as regedit export.  What needs to be changed to have it return an array that includes the blank line?

Here's my code if that's helpful:

```
private static string RegMultiStringExtraction(RegistryKey UsersSubKey, string Key)
    {
        string[] InputStrs = (string[])UsersSubKey.GetValue(Key, Environment.NewLine, RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string str in InputStrs)
        {
            char[] Values = str.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char letter in Values)
            {
                int ValueInt = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
                sb.Append(ValueInt.ToString("x"));
                sb.Append(",00,");
                if (Values.Length == 0)
                {
                    if (sb.Length == 0)
                    {
                        sb.Append("00,");
                    }
                    else if (sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        sb.Append(",00,");
                    }
                }
            }
            sb.Append("00,00,");
        }

        string Value = ('"' + Key.ToString() + @"""=" + "hex(7):" + sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
        return Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double null-terminated strings cannot contain empty lines. An attempt to include empty lines means including two consecutive nulls, and that is interpreted as termination rather than an empty line. Raymond Chen [discussed this quirk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx) much more eloquently that I can.

Perhaps you can save to `REG_SZ` and use `Environment.NewLine` as a delimiter.

Comment: That's just the thing, regedit export gives hex(7):3a,00,00,00,00,00 as the output, which DOES contain an empty line.  It can be imported as well, and the import also works, creating the MultiString which indeed does contain the empty line that the export file would indicate it should.

Comment: You can stick as many nulls in there as you want. Once the parser encounters two in succession, it regards the list as having been terminated.

Comment: Also, my question is why does regedit export give hex(7):3a,00,00,00,00,00 as the value (which works) and RegistryKey.GetValue give only an array element for the non-empty lines in the MultiString.  If regedit can create a .reg file that properly includes the double-null, why doesn't RegistryKey.GetValue even have an element for that line in the MultiString?

Comment: That's just it, the parser doesn't.  If you import the following as a .reg file, it indeed parses it and puts an empty line in the MultiString:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\test]
"test"=hex(7):3a,00,00,00,00,00

Comment: I just tried to enter a Multi String with a blank line into regedit. It produced this error message: 
"Data of type REG_MULTI_SZ cannot contain empty strings.
Registry Editor will remove the empty string found."
Sure you can stuff in hex data to confound it, but, as I said, double null-terminated strings cannot contain empty lines.

Comment: The regedit viewer will display empty lines if you put in mal-formed data line in your question, but won't let you save a multi-string with empty lines. Since you are putting invalid data in the registry, I think it's reasonable for regedit to interpret that as it pleases. The rules are, "no empty strings". If you try to go against that, expect pain.